# LaTeX symbol formatting

Tags: symbols, wolfram-mathematica

```
\int_{\mathbb R^D} \Delta S \cdot S \, dx 
 = -\int_{\mathbb R^D} \nabla S\cdot \nabla S\, dx  
 = \mean{(\nabla S)^2}
```

I want to write average symbol on `$(\nabla S)^2$` but it is not workig. 
How can I write?
[image]

Comment: Do you mean `\overline{..}`?

Comment: \mean{} this symbol

Comment: @Forhad If you need using `\mean`, `\def\mean{\overline}` should be a solution, but probably with an usage as in my answer.

Comment: @Forhad Please, take a look at the Table 152, pp. 54 in http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf‎

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
\int_{\mathbb R^D} \Delta S \cdot S \, dx 
= -\int_{\mathbb R^D} \nabla S\cdot \nabla S\, dx  
= \overline{(\nabla )^2 S}
```

or, as is suggested in comment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\def\mean#1{\left< #1 \right>}

\[
\int_{\mathbb R^D} \Delta S \cdot S \, dx = -\int_{\mathbb R^D} \nabla S\cdot \nabla S\, dx  = \mean{(\nabla S)^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

with the following result:

[image]

Comment: cant we do this by angle bracket?
or by using   
\mean{}  symbol?

Comment: @Forhad Are you thinking about `\def\mean#1{\left< #1 \right>}`?

Comment: see the edit please